# Insert "Infinity" value in DF16_DEC column

Tags: abap

I have a table that has column of type `DF16_DEC`. Since this type is represented by `decfloat16` in ABAP and the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/abenconversion_type_decfloat.htm) of this type says that "Infinity" can be a value of this column.

> In ABAP invalid decimal floating point numbers are the special values "Infinity", "Inf", "NaN" and "sNaN", which represent infinity or invalid numbers and are designated in standard IEEE-754-2008.

So my question is how can I insert Infinity value in `DF16_DEC` column either via ABAP or via SE16?

Comment: `In ABAP *invalid* decimal floating point numbers are the special values...`

Comment: I think the highlighted passage just denotes that infinity values which are valid by IEEE-754-2008 standard, are essentially invalid by ABAP environment, so you can't assign them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ABAP does not support infinity or NaN values for decfloats (or for regular `TYPE f` floating point variables, for that matter). Any attempt to generate such a value through mathematical operations will result in a runtime error.

So if you want to put a value in your table which represents "no limit" or "higher than anything you will ever encounter", then the next best option would be to use the highest possible legal values. Which you can find in the constants `cl_abap_math=>max_decfloat16` and `cl_abap_math=>max_decfloat34` respectively.

Comment: Or build your own flag column around it, should the possibility of modification exist.